# sql query not giving expected results in sql server

Tags: sql

I am using sql server and this is my table structure

```
start end interval
1     3   1
9     12  1
16    20  2
100   120 5
```

expected result

```
1
2
3
9
10
11
12
16
18
20
100
105
110
115
120
```

i tried this before posting here

```
select start as result,end1,interval
from table
union
select result+1,interval,end1,interval 
from table
```

Comment: What is the logic you were trying to write? How is the expected result is calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect place to use a [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  The following code should give you the answer you're looking for:

```
;WITH IntervalCTE AS
(
  SELECT [start] AS Value, [end], [interval]
  FROM T
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [Value] + [interval], [end], [interval]
  FROM IntervalCTE
  WHERE [Value] < [end]
)
SELECT Value FROM IntervalCTE ORDER BY Value
```

I've also created a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a8cab/7) that you can look at.